# apps script vlookup not found?

Tags: google-apps-script, vlookup

I rearranged some columns and now my code isn't working. I'm trying to use vlookup to get values from another table.

```
var name = ss.getRange('G'+lastRow);
name.setValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###","Form Responses!Q:AA"),8,false)');
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
name.copyTo(name,{contentsOnly:true});
```

The table that I need to fill in:
[image]

The table that I am using to look up info:
[image]

Right now when I run the script, the cell just freaks out and gives the error:
Error
Did not find value 'Form Responses_Images/20ba4a5c.Upload.040416.jpg' in VLOOKUP evaluation.

But as you can see both tables have the value `Form Responses_Images/20ba4a5c.Upload.040416.jpg` in it?

Comment: Hi, Did my answer work for you ? Let me know so I can modify it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the `importrange` function and the column index. Start from column `V` and get the `3`rd column after that.

Replace:

```
name.setValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###","Form Responses!Q:AA"),8,false)');
```

with:

```
name.setValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###","Form Responses!V:AA"),3,false)');
```